# SPARQL Update not working

Tags: sparql

I am trying to perform a simple update of the value of a property that that has a given resource as its subject.

Here is my query:

```
WITH  <http://127.0.0.1:3000/dendro_graph>  
DELETE {   <http://127.0.0.1:3000/project/datanotes/records/teste/filho%20do%20teste>   <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/creator>  ?o0 .

} 
INSERT 
{ 
  <http://127.0.0.1:3000/project/datanotes/records/teste/filho%20do%20teste>    <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/creator>    "creator1"  .

} 
WHERE {   <http://127.0.0.1:3000/project/datanotes/records/teste/filho%20do%20teste>   <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/creator>  ?o0 .

}
```

The result of this is that the delete is executed, but the insert is not; I end up destroying all instances of the property, but no new value is added.

If I remove the WHERE clause, I end up with duplicate triples, because it seems the DELETE is not executed.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

This code produces the duplicates:

```
WITH  <http://127.0.0.1:3000/dendro_graph>  
DELETE 
{ 
<http://127.0.0.1:3000/project/datanotes/records/teste/filho%20do%20teste>   <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/creator>  ?o0 .

} 
INSERT 
{ 
  <http://127.0.0.1:3000/project/datanotes/records/teste/filho%20do%20teste>    <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/creator>    "creator1"  .

}
```

Comment: Which SPARQL engine and which version are you using?

Comment: When you say "no WHERE clause" I assume you mean "WHERE {}" else it's a syntax error.

When "WHERE {}" is uses, ?o0 is not bound so nothing gets DELETE'd.

Comment: Hi Andy, I'm using Virtuoso Version: 06.01.3127. When you say ?o0 is not bound, you mean there is no correspondence between the ?o0 in the DELETE clause and the WHERE clause? If that is the case, how can I delete all the triples that have the subject and predicate specified, like  `<http://127.0.0.1:3000/project/datanotes/records/teste/filho%20do%20teste>   <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/creator>  ?o0 .´, but where I do not know the object and then perform the insert? Thanks

Comment: I was already about to give up on this and run two queries, but this is really bad... It is more heavy on the database, and if there is an error between deletion and insertion it will be left inconsistent...

Comment: Check my edited answer for the code without the WHERE clause, which generates the duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query without the WHERE clause is not a legal SPARQL expression, and should have resulted in a syntax error. If the engine you're using accepts this, then that is a bug in that engine.

At first glance, ditto for the earlier operation, which you say deletes but does not insert: as far as I can see the SPARQL expression is correct, and if as you say the insert part does not get executed, that means you've discovered a bug in the engine that executes it. I recommend you get in touch with the developers directly.

Comment: As of today, I tested that same query with the most stable version of Virtuoso Open Source (Version: 07.00.3203 Build: Oct 20 2013) and it validates and runs. The result is : Modify <http://127.0.0.1:3000/dendro_graph>, delete 0 (or less) and insert 1 (or less) triples -- done.

I am just about to give up on all this SPARQL stuff, gotta be honest. Seems excellent on paper, but I already trashed a whole project using OrientDB, and this one is going the same way.

Comment: I'll try to reach the developers in the mailing list, just had to make sure it was not fixed in the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround I used to get this working (finally thank God). It seems you can specify several operations to be executed over the graph in a single operation using the semicolon `;`.

I ended up specifying the `DELETE` statement and then the `UPDATE` one

Check this out for code sample : [SPARQL Update example for updating more than one triple in a single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502398/sparql-update-example-for-updating-more-than-one-triple-in-a-single-query)