# Updating a data property of an individual based on given id

Tags: c#, sparql, ontology, dotnetrdf

i want to update a data property (AccessState) of any individual based on its ID(ActuatorID). i have used [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502398/sparql-update-example-for-updating-more-than-one-triple-in-a-single-query) for help. my code does not give me any error but it does not change the ontology. can anyone please point out my error. thanks in advance

heres my ontology

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
    <!ENTITY rdf 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#'>
    <!ENTITY rdfs 'http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#'>
    <!ENTITY xsd 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#'>
    <!ENTITY xml 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace'>
    <!ENTITY ap 'http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/ActuatorProvider#'>
    <!ENTITY owl 'http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#'>
    <!ENTITY ace_lexicon 'http://attempto.ifi.uzh.ch/ace_lexicon#'>
]>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/ActuatorProvider#" xmlns:ap="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/ActuatorProvider#" xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" xmlns:ace_lexicon="http://attempto.ifi.uzh.ch/ace_lexicon#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <owl:AnnotationProperty rdf:about="&ace_lexicon;CN_pl">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;AnnotationProperty" />
  </owl:AnnotationProperty>
  <owl:AnnotationProperty rdf:about="&ace_lexicon;CN_sg">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;AnnotationProperty" />
  </owl:AnnotationProperty>
  <owl:AnnotationProperty rdf:about="&ace_lexicon;PN_sg">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;AnnotationProperty" />
  </owl:AnnotationProperty>
  <owl:AnnotationProperty rdf:about="&ace_lexicon;TV_pl">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;AnnotationProperty" />
  </owl:AnnotationProperty>
  <owl:AnnotationProperty rdf:about="&ace_lexicon;TV_sg">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;AnnotationProperty" />
  </owl:AnnotationProperty>
  <owl:AnnotationProperty rdf:about="&ace_lexicon;TV_vbg">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;AnnotationProperty" />
  </owl:AnnotationProperty>
  <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/ActuatorProvider">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;Ontology" />
  </owl:Ontology>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="&ap;APServices">
    <ace_lexicon:CN_pl>APServiceses</ace_lexicon:CN_pl>
    <ace_lexicon:CN_sg>APServices</ace_lexicon:CN_sg>
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;AccessState">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Actuating_Device" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&ap;ActuatingDevice1">
    <ace_lexicon:PN_sg>ActuatingDevice1</ace_lexicon:PN_sg>
    <ap:AccessState rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">online</ap:AccessState>
    <ap:ActuatorCode rdf:datatype="&xsd;integer">1</ap:ActuatorCode>
    <ap:ActuatorExplain rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">"TemperatureControl"</ap:ActuatorExplain>
    <ap:ActuatorID rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">"SD01"</ap:ActuatorID>
    <ap:ActuatorName rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">"Fan"</ap:ActuatorName>
    <ap:ConnectsTo rdf:resource="&ap;ActuatorMiddleware1" />
    <ap:PowerConsumption rdf:datatype="&xsd;integer">400</ap:PowerConsumption>
    <ap:productTime rdf:datatype="&xsd;dateTime">2015-10-02T00:00:00-05:00</ap:productTime>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&ap;Actuating_Device" />
  </owl:NamedIndividual>
  <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&ap;ActuatingDevice2">
    <ace_lexicon:PN_sg>ActuatingDevice2</ace_lexicon:PN_sg>
    <ap:AccessState rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">offline
</ap:AccessState>
    <ap:ActuatorCode rdf:datatype="&xsd;integer">2</ap:ActuatorCode>
    <ap:ActuatorExplain rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">"AirConditioner"</ap:ActuatorExplain>
    <ap:ActuatorID rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">"DS02"</ap:ActuatorID>
    <ap:ActuatorName rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">"LabConditioner"</ap:ActuatorName>
    <ap:ConnectsTo rdf:resource="&ap;ActuatorMiddleware1" />
    <ap:PowerConsumption rdf:datatype="&xsd;integer">1300</ap:PowerConsumption>
  </owl:NamedIndividual>
  <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&ap;ActuatingDevice3">
    <ace_lexicon:PN_sg>ActuatingDevice3</ace_lexicon:PN_sg>
    <ap:ActuatorCode rdf:datatype="&xsd;integer">3</ap:ActuatorCode>
    <ap:ActuatorExplain rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">"Printer"</ap:ActuatorExplain>
    <ap:ActuatorID rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">"PT03"</ap:ActuatorID>
    <ap:ActuatorName rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">"SamsungPrinter"</ap:ActuatorName>
    <ap:ConnectsTo rdf:resource="&ap;ActuatorMiddleware2" />
    <ap:PowerConsumption rdf:datatype="&xsd;integer">120</ap:PowerConsumption>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&ap;Actuating_Device" />
  </owl:NamedIndividual>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="&ap;Actuating_Device">
    <ace_lexicon:CN_pl>Actuating_Devices</ace_lexicon:CN_pl>
    <ace_lexicon:CN_sg>Actuating_Device</ace_lexicon:CN_sg>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&ap;Device" />
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:nodeID="autos10" />
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:nodeID="autos11" />
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;ActuatorCode">
    <ace_lexicon:TV_pl>ActuatorCode</ace_lexicon:TV_pl>
    <ace_lexicon:TV_sg>ActuatorCodes</ace_lexicon:TV_sg>
    <ace_lexicon:TV_vbg>ActuatorCoded</ace_lexicon:TV_vbg>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Actuating_Device" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;integer" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;ActuatorExplain">
    <ace_lexicon:TV_pl>ActuatorExplain</ace_lexicon:TV_pl>
    <ace_lexicon:TV_sg>ActuatorExplains</ace_lexicon:TV_sg>
    <ace_lexicon:TV_vbg>ActuatorExplained</ace_lexicon:TV_vbg>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Actuating_Device" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&owl;topDataProperty" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;ActuatorID">
    <ace_lexicon:TV_pl>ActuatorID</ace_lexicon:TV_pl>
    <ace_lexicon:TV_sg>ActuatorIDs</ace_lexicon:TV_sg>
    <ace_lexicon:TV_vbg>ActuatorIDed</ace_lexicon:TV_vbg>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Actuating_Device" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&ap;ActuatorMiddleware1">
    <ace_lexicon:PN_sg>ActuatorMiddleware1</ace_lexicon:PN_sg>
    <ap:ConnectsTo rdf:resource="&ap;ActuatorServiceProvider1" />
    <ap:MiddlewareCode rdf:datatype="&xsd;integer">1</ap:MiddlewareCode>
    <ap:MiddlewareID rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">"MW101"</ap:MiddlewareID>
    <ap:MiddlewareRight rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">false</ap:MiddlewareRight>
    <ap:Use rdf:resource="&ap;ControlService1" />
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&ap;Actuator_Middleware" />
  </owl:NamedIndividual>
  <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&ap;ActuatorMiddleware2">
    <ace_lexicon:PN_sg>ActuatorMiddleware2</ace_lexicon:PN_sg>
    <ap:ConnectsTo rdf:resource="&ap;ActuatorServiceProvider1" />
    <ap:MiddlewareCode rdf:datatype="&xsd;integer">2</ap:MiddlewareCode>
    <ap:MiddlewareID rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">"MW102"</ap:MiddlewareID>
    <ap:MiddlewareRight rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">true</ap:MiddlewareRight>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&ap;Actuator_Middleware" />
  </owl:NamedIndividual>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="&ap;ActuatorModel">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:nodeID="autos12" />
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;ActuatorName">
    <ace_lexicon:TV_pl>ActuatorName</ace_lexicon:TV_pl>
    <ace_lexicon:TV_sg>ActuatorNames</ace_lexicon:TV_sg>
    <ace_lexicon:TV_vbg>ActuatorNamed</ace_lexicon:TV_vbg>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Actuating_Device" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&ap;ActuatorServiceProvider1">
    <ace_lexicon:PN_sg>ActuatorServiceProvider1</ace_lexicon:PN_sg>
    <ap:ConnectsTo rdf:resource="&ap;ActuatorSupportToolbox1" />
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&ap;Actuator_Service_Provider" />
  </owl:NamedIndividual>
  <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&ap;ActuatorSupportToolbox1">
    <ace_lexicon:PN_sg>ActuatorSupportToolbox1</ace_lexicon:PN_sg>
    <ap:Perform rdf:resource="&ap;Management1" />
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&ap;Actuator_Support_Toolbox" />
  </owl:NamedIndividual>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="&ap;Actuator_Content_Service">
    <ace_lexicon:CN_pl>Actuator_Content_Services</ace_lexicon:CN_pl>
    <ace_lexicon:CN_sg>Actuator_Content_Service</ace_lexicon:CN_sg>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&ap;APServices" />
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="&ap;Actuator_Control_Service">
    <ace_lexicon:CN_pl>Actuator_Control_Services</ace_lexicon:CN_pl>
    <ace_lexicon:CN_sg>Actuator_Control_Service</ace_lexicon:CN_sg>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&ap;APServices" />
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="&ap;Actuator_Info_Management">
    <ace_lexicon:CN_pl>Actuator_Info_Managements</ace_lexicon:CN_pl>
    <ace_lexicon:CN_sg>Actuator_Info_Management</ace_lexicon:CN_sg>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&ap;Management" />
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:nodeID="autos13" />
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="&ap;Actuator_Middleware">
    <ace_lexicon:CN_pl>Actuator_Middlewares</ace_lexicon:CN_pl>
    <ace_lexicon:CN_sg>Actuator_Middleware</ace_lexicon:CN_sg>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:nodeID="autos14" />
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:nodeID="autos15" />
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="&ap;Actuator_Provider_Service">
    <ace_lexicon:CN_pl>Actuator_Provider_Services</ace_lexicon:CN_pl>
    <ace_lexicon:CN_sg>Actuator_Provider_Service</ace_lexicon:CN_sg>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&ap;APServices" />
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="&ap;Actuator_Service_Provider">
    <ace_lexicon:CN_pl>Actuator_Service_Providers</ace_lexicon:CN_pl>
    <ace_lexicon:CN_sg>Actuator_Service_Provider</ace_lexicon:CN_sg>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:nodeID="autos16" />
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="&ap;Actuator_State">
    <ace_lexicon:CN_pl>Actuator_States</ace_lexicon:CN_pl>
    <ace_lexicon:CN_sg>Actuator_State</ace_lexicon:CN_sg>
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="&ap;Actuator_Support_Toolbox">
    <ace_lexicon:CN_pl>Actuator_Support_Toolboxes</ace_lexicon:CN_pl>
    <ace_lexicon:CN_sg>Actuator_Support_Toolbox</ace_lexicon:CN_sg>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:nodeID="autos17" />
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&ap;ConnectsTo">
    <ace_lexicon:TV_pl>ConnectsTo</ace_lexicon:TV_pl>
    <ace_lexicon:TV_sg>ConnectsToes</ace_lexicon:TV_sg>
    <ace_lexicon:TV_vbg>ConnectsToed</ace_lexicon:TV_vbg>
  </owl:ObjectProperty>
  <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&ap;ControlService1">
    <ace_lexicon:PN_sg>ControlService1</ace_lexicon:PN_sg>
  </owl:NamedIndividual>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="&ap;Device">
    <ace_lexicon:CN_pl>Devices</ace_lexicon:CN_pl>
    <ace_lexicon:CN_sg>Device</ace_lexicon:CN_sg>
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;Field_Key">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Time_Attribute" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="&ap;Management">
    <ace_lexicon:CN_pl>Managements</ace_lexicon:CN_pl>
    <ace_lexicon:CN_sg>Management</ace_lexicon:CN_sg>
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&ap;Management1">
    <ace_lexicon:PN_sg>Management1</ace_lexicon:PN_sg>
  </owl:NamedIndividual>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;MiddlewareCode">
    <ace_lexicon:TV_pl>MiddlewareCode</ace_lexicon:TV_pl>
    <ace_lexicon:TV_sg>MiddlewareCodes</ace_lexicon:TV_sg>
    <ace_lexicon:TV_vbg>MiddlewareCoded</ace_lexicon:TV_vbg>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Actuator_Middleware" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;long" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;MiddlewareID">
    <ace_lexicon:TV_pl>MiddlewareID</ace_lexicon:TV_pl>
    <ace_lexicon:TV_sg>MiddlewareIDs</ace_lexicon:TV_sg>
    <ace_lexicon:TV_vbg>MiddlewareIDed</ace_lexicon:TV_vbg>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Actuator_Middleware" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;MiddlewareRight">
    <ace_lexicon:TV_pl>MiddlewareRight</ace_lexicon:TV_pl>
    <ace_lexicon:TV_sg>MiddlewareRights</ace_lexicon:TV_sg>
    <ace_lexicon:TV_vbg>MiddlewareRighted</ace_lexicon:TV_vbg>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Actuator_Middleware" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="&ap;Middleware_Access_Management">
    <ace_lexicon:CN_pl>Middleware_Access_Managements</ace_lexicon:CN_pl>
    <ace_lexicon:CN_sg>Middleware_Access_Management</ace_lexicon:CN_sg>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&ap;Management" />
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:nodeID="autos18" />
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;ModelBlend">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;ActuatorModel" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;ModelCode">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;ActuatorModel" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;long" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;ModelName">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;ActuatorModel" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="&ap;Multistep_Attribute">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;Class" />
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;Multistep_Code">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Multistep_Attribute" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;long" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;Multistep_Explain">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Multistep_Attribute" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;Multistep_Name">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Multistep_Attribute" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="&ap;Mutlistep_Step">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;Class" />
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&ap;Perform">
    <ace_lexicon:TV_pl>Perform</ace_lexicon:TV_pl>
    <ace_lexicon:TV_sg>Performs</ace_lexicon:TV_sg>
    <ace_lexicon:TV_vbg>Performed</ace_lexicon:TV_vbg>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Actuator_Support_Toolbox" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&ap;Management" />
  </owl:ObjectProperty>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;PowerConsumption">
    <ace_lexicon:TV_pl>PowerConsumption</ace_lexicon:TV_pl>
    <ace_lexicon:TV_sg>PowerConsumptions</ace_lexicon:TV_sg>
    <ace_lexicon:TV_vbg>PowerConsumptioned</ace_lexicon:TV_vbg>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Actuating_Device" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;double" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&ap;Provide">
    <ace_lexicon:TV_pl>Provide</ace_lexicon:TV_pl>
    <ace_lexicon:TV_sg>Provides</ace_lexicon:TV_sg>
    <ace_lexicon:TV_vbg>Provided</ace_lexicon:TV_vbg>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Actuator_Service_Provider" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&ap;APServices" />
  </owl:ObjectProperty>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="&ap;Range_Attribute">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;Class" />
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;Range_Code">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Range_Attribute" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;long" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;Range_Explain">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Range_Attribute" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;Range_Max_Value">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Range_Attribute" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;float" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;Range_Min_Value">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Range_Attribute" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;float" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;Range_Name">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Range_Attribute" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="&ap;Service_Info_Management">
    <ace_lexicon:CN_pl>Service_Info_Managements</ace_lexicon:CN_pl>
    <ace_lexicon:CN_sg>Service_Info_Management</ace_lexicon:CN_sg>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&ap;Management" />
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;Step_Code">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Mutlistep_Step" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;long" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;Step_Name">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Mutlistep_Step" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;Step_Value">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Mutlistep_Step" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;long" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;SwitchCode">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Switch_Attribute" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;long" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="&ap;Switch_Attribute">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;Class" />
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;Switch_Explain">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Switch_Attribute" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;Switch_Name">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Switch_Attribute" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;Switch_Off_State">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Switch_Attribute" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;Switch_On_State">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Switch_Attribute" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="&ap;Time_Attribute">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;Class" />
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;Time_Code">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Time_Attribute" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;long" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;Time_Explain">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Time_Attribute" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;Time_Name">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Time_Attribute" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;TypeCode">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;TypeInformation" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;long" />
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&owl;topDataProperty" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;TypeId">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;TypeInformation" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="&ap;TypeInformation">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;Class" />
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;TypeName">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;TypeInformation" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&ap;Use">
    <ace_lexicon:TV_pl>Use</ace_lexicon:TV_pl>
    <ace_lexicon:TV_sg>Uses</ace_lexicon:TV_sg>
    <ace_lexicon:TV_vbg>Used</ace_lexicon:TV_vbg>
  </owl:ObjectProperty>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&ap;hasDuration">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Actuating_Device" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&ap;Time_Attribute" />
  </owl:ObjectProperty>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&ap;hasModel">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;ObjectProperty" />
  </owl:ObjectProperty>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&ap;hasMultistep">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Actuating_Device" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&ap;Multistep_Attribute" />
  </owl:ObjectProperty>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&ap;hasRange">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Actuating_Device" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&ap;Range_Attribute" />
  </owl:ObjectProperty>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&ap;hasState">
    <ace_lexicon:TV_pl>hasState</ace_lexicon:TV_pl>
    <ace_lexicon:TV_sg>hasStates</ace_lexicon:TV_sg>
    <ace_lexicon:TV_vbg>hasStated</ace_lexicon:TV_vbg>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;FunctionalProperty" />
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Device" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&ap;Actuator_State" />
  </owl:ObjectProperty>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&ap;hasStep">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Actuating_Device" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&ap;Mutlistep_Step" />
  </owl:ObjectProperty>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&ap;hasType">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;ActuatorModel" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&ap;TypeInformation" />
  </owl:ObjectProperty>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&ap;productTime">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&ap;Actuating_Device" />
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;dateTime" />
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:Restriction rdf:nodeID="autos10">
    <owl:onClass rdf:resource="&ap;ActuatorModel" />
    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&ap;hasModel" />
    <owl:qualifiedCardinality rdf:datatype="&xsd;nonNegativeInteger">1</owl:qualifiedCardinality>
  </owl:Restriction>
  <owl:Restriction rdf:nodeID="autos11">
    <owl:onClass rdf:resource="&ap;Actuator_State" />
    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&ap;hasState" />
    <owl:qualifiedCardinality rdf:datatype="&xsd;nonNegativeInteger">1</owl:qualifiedCardinality>
  </owl:Restriction>
  <owl:Restriction rdf:nodeID="autos12">
    <owl:onClass rdf:resource="&ap;TypeInformation" />
    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&ap;hasType" />
    <owl:qualifiedCardinality rdf:datatype="&xsd;nonNegativeInteger">1</owl:qualifiedCardinality>
  </owl:Restriction>
  <owl:Restriction rdf:nodeID="autos13">
    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&ap;Use" />
    <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="&ap;Actuator_Content_Service" />
  </owl:Restriction>
  <owl:Restriction rdf:nodeID="autos14">
    <owl:maxQualifiedCardinality rdf:datatype="&xsd;nonNegativeInteger">1</owl:maxQualifiedCardinality>
    <owl:onClass rdf:resource="&ap;Actuator_Service_Provider" />
    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&ap;ConnectsTo" />
  </owl:Restriction>
  <owl:Restriction rdf:nodeID="autos15">
    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&ap;Use" />
    <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="&ap;Actuator_Control_Service" />
  </owl:Restriction>
  <owl:Restriction rdf:nodeID="autos16">
    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&ap;ConnectsTo" />
    <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="&ap;Actuator_Support_Toolbox" />
  </owl:Restriction>
  <owl:Restriction rdf:nodeID="autos17">
    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&ap;Perform" />
    <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="&ap;Management" />
  </owl:Restriction>
  <owl:Restriction rdf:nodeID="autos18">
    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&ap;Use" />
    <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="&ap;Actuator_Content_Service" />
  </owl:Restriction>
</rdf:RDF>
```

the code that im using is given here

```cs
string actID = txtActuatorId.Text;
        string actState = txtActautorState.Text;

    TripleStore store = new TripleStore();
    Graph mygraph = new Graph();
    FileLoader.Load(mygraph, "D:/ActuatorServiceProvider.owl", new RdfXmlParser());
    mygraph.BaseUri = null;
    store.Add(mygraph);
    SparqlUpdateParser myparser = new SparqlUpdateParser();
    SparqlParameterizedString querystring = new SparqlParameterizedString();
    querystring.CommandText = "PREFIX  ap: <http://www.semanticweb.org/faiza/ontologies/2014/10/ActuatorProvider> " +
            "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>" +
            "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>" +
            "PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>" +
            "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>" +

     "DELETE {?ind ap:AccessState ?t.} " +
    "INSERT {?ind ap:AccessState \"" + actState + "\"^^xsd:string.} " +
    "WHERE {?ind ap:ActuatorID \"" + actID + "\"^^xsd:string.} ";

    SparqlUpdateCommandSet cmds = myparser.ParseFromString(querystring);
    LeviathanUpdateProcessor processor = new LeviathanUpdateProcessor(store);
    processor.ProcessCommandSet(cmds);
    mygraph.SaveToFile("D:/ActuatorServiceProvider.owl");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data looks a little strange in that you actually appear to have double quotes included in the values which is unusual e.g.:

```
<ap:ActuatorExplain rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">"AirConditioner"</ap:ActuatorExplain>
<ap:ActuatorID rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">"DS02"</ap:ActuatorID>
<ap:ActuatorName rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">"LabConditioner"</ap:ActuatorName>
```

This would also explain why your update makes no change because you are searching for `id` whereas your data contains `"id"`.

You could fix your query by adding the quotes into your query but to be honest it looks like your actual data is broken and you should fix that by removing the unnecessary `"` around values.  Once your data is fixed then your query should work just fine.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer!! and for pointing out my mistake i did the corrections and got my answer.